# NAudio - Click removal like audacity

Tags: naudio

I have used NAudio to record sound and save it as .wav file.
So while recording there are some sound with high amplitude which makes the recording not suitable, there are some sound click which can be seen in audacity, but its typically high amplitude but short.
how to identify and skip them.
And can i perform sound calibration before recording.

thanks
sunil

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Audacity wiki page on click removal ([here](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Click_Removal)) it looks fairly simple... but probably isn't, in reality.

Using a sliding window - say the last second or so of samples - you can calculate the average amplitude of the waveform, then compare it against the amplitude of the current position (as an average over a small set of samples either side of where you're looking at).  This will give you an indication of whether the current sample group has an anomalous amplitude.  Find the highest magnitude samples in the group and cut them down to fit.  The Audacity wiki says they just do a linear interpolation between samples either side of the anomaly.

This should work OK for a few anomalous samples, but the bigger the duration of the click the worse the detection and the correction will be.  You'll need to fine-tune the detection and correction parameters to get a reasonable rate of detection.  It would probably also be a good idea to do an amplitude map for the entire waveform and check both sides of prospective clicks to help reduce the false-positive rate.

Another approach - possibly one that could be combined - would be to build a frequency profile across the waveform.  Various types of clicks will exhibit different variances from the surrounding frequencies.